# How to register member functions in map c++

Tags: c++, boost, listener, containers

I am trying to create a map to hold functions that can be registered and fired.  I cannot seem to get the correct bind / function / pointer syntax in order to get this compiling properly.

Here is what I have:  I have tried both boost::bind and boost:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

typedef const std::string& listenArg;
typedef void (*Actions)(listenArg str);

std::multimap<int, Actions> functions;

// fire in the hole!

void fire(int methods, listenArg arg0) {
    std::multimap<int, Actions>::iterator function = functions.find(methods);

    typedef std::pair<int, Actions> pear;

    for (function = functions.begin(); function != functions.end(); ++function) {
        (*(function->second))(arg0);
    }
}

void listen1(listenArg arg0) {
    std::cout << "listen1 called with " << arg0 << std::endl;
}

class RegisteringClass {
public:
    RegisteringClass();
    virtual ~RegisteringClass();

    void callMeBaby(listenArg str) {
        std::cout << "baby, i was called with " << str << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    const int key = 111;


    functions.insert(make_pair<int, Actions>(key, listen1));
    fire(key, "test");

    // make a registeringClass
    RegisteringClass reg;

    // register call me baby
    boost::function<void (listenArg) >
            fx(boost::bind(&RegisteringClass::callMeBaby, reg, _1));
    //std::bind(&RegisteringClass::callMeBaby, reg, _1);
    functions.insert(
            make_pair<int, Actions> (key, fx));

    // fire
    fire(key, "test2");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Neither `boost::function` nor the result type of `boost::bind` are convertible to a function pointer. Define `Actions` type as `boost::function` instead of raw function pointer.

Comment: Important to your question is that you seem to want to hold *both* the member function *and* the calling object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
typedef boost::function < void (listenArg) > Actions;
```

Should be used instead of function pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're telling the compiler that `Actions` is a non-member function pointer, and then you try to put a `boost::function` into a variable of that type. They're two totally unrelated types and such an assignment can't happen. You need to make your `Actions` typedef be a `boost::function<void (listenArg)>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `boost::function` template

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

typedef const std::string& listenArg;

typedef boost::function < void (listenArg) > Actions;
std::multimap<int, Actions> functions;
```